# How can i turn off gevent exception traceback output?

Tags: python, gevent

I have an exception in each greenlet which can handled only by the upper level that calls gevent.joinall.
I tried to use link_exception with a callback, but when exception rised gevent first write all the tracesback to std.err then the callback is called.
so How can I turn it off completely?

Python 2.7.6 Gevent 1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

It's by design apparently - https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/55

This works in 1.0.1: `gevent.hub.Hub.NOT_ERROR = (Exception,)`. However there is no guarantee that this will continue to work in future versions.